# Formulate optimization with intermediate variables

Tags: optimization

I have the following problem

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{6\times1}$ be unknown decision variables, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ is a known vector, and $A$ is a known matrix. We formulate the following optimization problem

\begin{array}{lc}
 \text{minimize} & \Big\lVert \left[x_1, x_2,x_3\right]^\text{T} \Big\rVert_2  \\
 \text{subject to} \\
 & \det R > 0\\
 & A x = b \\
 \text{where} \\
 & R(x), A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times6}
\end{array}

The solution process includes iterating $x_1,x_2,x_3$ while $x_4,x_5,x_6$ are uniquely determined for each iteration of $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Then $x_4,x_5,x_6$ seem to be something like ***intermediate variables***. **Is this the proper way to formulate the optimization problem with respect to $x_4,x_5,x_6$?** They can be any values as long at the constraints are met. But, as soon as we choose $x_1,x_2,x_3$ then $x_4,x_5,x_6$ are uniquely determined.

Comment: Is $A$ also known?  What is $R(x)$?

Comment: A is also known. I updated the text accordingly. $R(x)$, I don't think, is important to my question and could be distracting. It is a matrix of all the variables in $x$.